# Добавление заголовков в файл при записи

Tags: python, list, список, запись

Существует три списка, которые записываются в файл в виде трех столбцов

`0.0001 49.67720674493453   0.7821777109870398
0.005   47.763109451848116  0.7633853584398312
0.01    46.867992999939155  0.7547741579779546
0.05    43.2951370171333    0.7215259482235312
0.1 40.83258991438261   0.6996893972778152
0.5 32.29431950631768   0.6323011426381819`

с помощью кода:

`file = open("save1.dat", "w")
for index in range(len(compres)):
    file.write(str(freqs[index]) + "\t" + str(compres[index]) + "\t" + str(compphase[index]) + "\n")
file.close()`

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при записи файл имел вид:

`First    Second               Third
0.0001  49.67720674493453   0.7821777109870398
0.005   47.763109451848116  0.7633853584398312
0.01    46.867992999939155  0.7547741579779546
0.05    43.2951370171333    0.7215259482235312
0.1 40.83258991438261   0.6996893972778152
0.5 32.29431950631768   0.6323011426381819`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените то что лежит в переменных `a` `b` и `c` на свои данные, то что в `a` это данные первого столбца соответственно `b` и `c` второй и третий. А вообще для таких целей используйте csv формат в файлах и проблем не будет.

```
headers = ['first', 'second', 'third']

a, b, c = [111111, 222222, 333333], [444444, 555555, 666666], [77777, 888888, 99999]

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % tuple(h for h in headers))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        f.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (a[i], b[i], c[i]))
```